# WS MQ - remove message from a queue

Tags: queue, websphere

I am using .net framework to work with ws queues. Is it possible to remove/delete a message from a queue?

Answer (score 0):

Retrieving it will remove it from the queue. You can then discard the retrieved message if you don't want to do anything with it.

```
    // Hit up MSMQ for list of new messages
    var queuedMessages = myMessageQueue.GetAllMessages();

    // Receive actual message to remove from the message queue
    var messages = new List<Message>();
    foreach (var queuedMessage in queuedMessages)
    {
        // Receive the message, which removes it from the queue. 
        try
        {
            messages.Add(this.messageQueue.ReceiveById(queuedMessage.Id));
        }
        // If it's already been removed, we skip over it.
        // TODO: Should try to catch only the "removed" exception
        catch (Exception)
        {
            continue;
        }
    }
```

return messages;

Comment: So the only way to remove a message from a websphere queue is to simply receive it ?

Comment: It's not the *only* way - you can clear the queue from runmqsc, i.e. clear ql(system.default.local.queue), if it's not-persistent you can restart the queue manager, or you can send with an expiry time etc. But the very point of WMQ and other messaging providers is that in the absence of defined non-persistence, expiry etc., messages are held until an application receives them. EDIT: it's a bit unclear from the context what the messaging provider is, the title says WS MQ (=WebSphere MQ?), the response says MSMQ and "WebSphere Queue" might be the WAS messaging provider. I'm assuming WMQ here